# Creating an inverse of an Oracle view - EDITED

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that I need to a create view which shows rows from the OBJECT table that don't appear in the OBJECT_VALUES table, for each month;
OBJECT:

```
+------+--------+
| ID   | NAME   |
+------+--------+
| 1    | OBJ1   |
| 2    | OBJ2   |
| 3    | OBJ3   |
+---------------+
```

And OBJECT_VALUES:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| ID   |OBJECT_ID| MONTH   |
+------+---------+---------+
| 1    |    1    | 2016-4  |
| 2    |    3    | 2016-4  |
| 3    |    2    | 2016-5  |
| 4    |    3    | 2016-5  |
| 5    |    3    | 2016-6  |
| 6    |    1    | 2016-7  |
+------+---------+---------+
```

The expected results:

```
+---------+--------+
|OBJECT_ID| MONTH  |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 2016-4 |
| 3       | 2016-4 |
| 2       | 2016-5 |
| 3       | 2016-5 |
| 3       | 2016-6 |
| 1       | 2016-7 |
+---------+--------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is the list of all OBJECTS per month that don't appear in the values for that month.

**EDIT:**
I posted the wrong expected results, I apologize - I am trying to get the inverse of the above expected results which makes the following the expected results:

```
+---------+--------+
|OBJECT_ID| MONTH  |
+---------+--------+
| 2       | 2016-4 |
| 1       | 2016-5 |
| 1       | 2016-6 |
| 2       | 2016-6 |
| 2       | 2016-7 |
| 3       | 2016-7 |
+---------+--------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your expected result seems to be `select object_id, month from object_values`.

Comment: I think something went wrong in your question, because the last table does not correspond to your requirement that the output records should not appear in `object_values`.

Comment: Are you sure you stated the right question ? I guess its  simple select which you needed from your query

Comment: I have edited the question - I had made a mistake on the expected results but I have corrected it on the edit. I am trying to get the inverse of the original expected results.

Comment: Suppose your `OBJECT_VALUES` didn't have ANY rows (for any `object_id`) for the month `2016-6`. Would you then need to see ALL the `oblect_id`'s in the result? And, what if the list was supposed to start with `2016-3` but there was no such month in `OBJECT_VALUES`? Are the "months of interest" given to you, or should they be between the min and the max of the `month` column in `OBJECT_VALUES`?

Comment: Thanks for a mind opener... I had not thought of it that far. Months were  not of interest when I asked the question, I was looking for something in between min and max of the month. But it would be nice to have it for the past 12 months, including months in which are not in OBJECT_VALUES as long as they are withing the past 12 months.

Comment: It is a pity your months are encoded with only one digit for the months, that does not sort well when you also need values for month 10, 11 and 12. Would you be able to move to 2-digits, zero padded?

Comment: Nicely written down question, too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for

> rows from the OBJECT table that don't appear in the OBJECT_VALUES table, for each month

The following query produces that:

```
select      object.id as object_id,
            months.month
from        (select distinct month
             from   object_values) months
cross join  object
left join   object_values
         on object.id = object_values.object_id
        and months.month = object_values.month
where       object_values.id is null
order by    2, 1
```

The output is:

```
+-----------+--------+
| object_id |  month |
+-----------+--------+
|       2   | 2016-4 |
|       1   | 2016-5 |
|       1   | 2016-6 |
|       2   | 2016-6 |
|       2   | 2016-7 |
|       3   | 2016-7 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Note that this is not the output you presented in the question, but according to your question, this should be the output.

#### Alternative covering 12 months

This variation on the above SQL statement, uses a different query for the nested `select` in order to retrieve exactly the last 12 months:

```
select      object.id as object_id,
            months.month
from        (select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'), -level), 'YYYY-fmMM') 
                     as month
                from dual
                connect by level <= 12) months
cross join  object
left join   object_values
         on object.id = object_values.object_id
        and months.month = object_values.month
where       object_values.id is null
order by    2, 1;
```

It is a pity your month strings have the the month number in one digit, which means that they don't sort well. If ever you change your data to use 2 digits for all months, then replace the `fmDD` in the date format to `DD`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had made a mistake in my question but your answer is in the right direction of what I am trying to achieve. I want all objects that don't have a specific date to appear with the date they don't appear in. Please see the edit of my question.

Comment: That is what I thought. Now my output corresponds to yours.

Comment: Did you check the SQL I posted? Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I checked the sql posted, it shows the records that are not in the values table at all, repeating them for each month; I just want the ID to be shown with the month in which it does not appear.

Comment: I don't understand. As I see it the output table is *exactly* the same as you posted near the end of your question. My SQL only shows the *id*, and *month*, and only those combinations which do not exist in *object_values*. Our result tables are exactly the same.

Comment: @trincot - this won't work quite right if there are no rows for any `id` for a given month... I asked the OP for clarification on that. You may need a partitioned outer join if, as one would expect, he would need all the id's listed in the output for that month.

Comment: I see what you mean, but that is not mentioned in the question, nor in the expected results table the OP posted. Otherwise there should have been output for 2016-3 and before.

Comment: Thank you very much, @trincot, this is exactly what I wanted and it works just how I wanted it. I am sorry for my comment from earlier - I had made a minor mistake in my query but afer seeing your comment I was able to see that I had made a mistake and corrected it. Thank you very much - have a wonderful day :-)

Comment: I added an alternative query that covers the 12 past months.

Answer (score 0):

```
select OBJECT_ID, MONTH from OBJECT_VALUES;
```